# R: replace values in data frame with respect to NAs as placeholders

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to replace the values in one data frame by values in another data frame given that a value exists in the first data frame.

The first data frame consists of values that are either 1 or 0 with NA's being placeholders.

```
a <- structure(list(A.1 = c(1L, 0L, NA, 1L, 1L, 0L), A.2 = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, NA, 1L, NA), A.3 = c(0L, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA), A.4 = c(NA, 
1L, 1L, NA, 0L, NA), A.5 = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), A.6 = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L)), .Names = c("A.1", "A.2", "A.3", "A.4", 
"A.5", "A.6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

The 2nd dataframe consists of the values that should replace the 1s or 0s with respect to he position of the NAs in the first data frame

```
r <- structure(list(R.1 = c(45L, 33L, 44L, 24L, 32L, 22L), R.2 = c(33L, 
99L, 44L, 25L, 25L, 33L), R.3 = c(22L, 77L, 22L, NA, 26L, NA), 
    R.4 = c(NA, NA, 32L, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("R.1", "R.2", 
"R.3", "R.4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

The goal is this:

```
d <- structure(list(D.1 = c(45L, 33L, NA, 24L, 32L, 22L), D.2 = c(33L, 
99L, 44L, NA, 25L, NA), D.3 = c(22L, NA, NA, 25L, NA, NA), D.4 = c(NA, 
77L, 44L, NA, 26L, NA), D.5 = c(NA, NA, 22L, NA, NA, NA), D.6 = c(NA, 
NA, 32L, NA, NA, 33L)), .Names = c("D.1", "D.2", "D.3", "D.4", 
"D.5", "D.6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Any & all suggestions welcome.

Comment: That goal looks just like the first input. Copy & paste error?

Comment: @MvG yeah, it was a copy and paste error. Sorry about that!

Comment: Why does your `d` have 5 rows when `a` and `r` have six?

Comment: Shouldn't the 4th row of `d` be `24 NA 25 NA NA NA`?

Comment: yes, my mistake again. The 4th row was missing. A lesson in why doing things by hand is no good. The example has been fixed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
d <- t(a)
d[!is.na(d)] <- t(r)[!is.na(t(r))]
t(d)
     A.1 A.2 A.3 A.4 A.5 A.6
[1,]  45  33  22  NA  NA  NA
[2,]  33  99  NA  77  NA  NA
[3,]  NA  44  NA  44  22  32
[4,]  24  NA  25  NA  NA  NA
[5,]  32  25  NA  26  NA  NA
[6,]  22  NA  NA  NA  NA  33
```

Also, notice that `t()` returns a matrix instead of data.frame

Answer (score 3):

```
d <- matrix(data=NA, ncol=ncol(a),nrow=nrow(a)) # Initialize matrix

replacements <- t(r) # Transpose R for na.omit()

# Replace
for (x in 1:nrow(a)) { 
  locations <- which(!is.na(a[x,]))
  d[x,locations] <- na.omit(replacements[,x])
  }
```

Comment: This works well too! Just forgot a comma after `data=NA` Cheers!